# How to change the Livechat bubble position in browser using react-livechat module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, livechat

I'm trying to change the bubble position of livechat.

I'm using this module from npm [LiveChat for React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-livechat)

Comment: have u tried any code. I think u can simply use CSS absolute position.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you do that in the LiveChat account configurations https://www.livechat.com/help/customize-your-chat/#what-options
[image]
You can only move to the right or left though, doing further customization would need some CSS code to override its styles

**UPDATE**

I checked the livechat official website and assuming they are using their own product, there should be a div with `id="chat-widget-container"` in your site, you could add a CSS rule to your styles to move that chat widget to the left or right

move it to the right

```
#chat-widget-container {
  right: 0px;
  left: unset;
}
```

move it to the left

```
#chat-widget-container {
  left: 0px;
  right: unset;
}
```

As this is a hackish solution it could break when they decide to change the container id

Comment: Is there a way to adjust it  directly on window load ?

Comment: @PanayiotisGeorgiou I updated my answer with a CSS workaround